What interfered with my expected OpenMP behavior in the custom operator of C++ TensorFlow 1.12?
I implemented my computation logic in C++ (actually using C++ code generated by PyTorch's Inductor), utilizing OpenMP to accelerate Tensor computations. For example, one of the functions is as follows:
extern "C" void cpp_fused_convolution_0(const float* in_ptr0,
                       const float* in_ptr1,
                       float* out_ptr0,
                       float* out_ptr1,
                       const long ks0)
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(64)
    {
        int t_nums = omp_get_num_threads();
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Current thread ID: %d, all thread nums: %d\n", tid, t_nums);
        {
            #pragma omp for
            for(long x0=static_cast<long>(0L); x0<static_cast<long>(ks0); x0+=static_cast<long>(1L))
            {
                #pragma GCC ivdep
                for(long x1=static_cast<long>(0L); x1<static_cast<long>(3L); x1+=static_cast<long>(1L))
                {
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(long x2=static_cast<long>(0L); x2<static_cast<long>(50176L); x2+=static_cast<long>(1L))
                    {
                        auto tmp0 = in_ptr0[static_cast<long>(x2 + (50176L*x1) + (150528L*x0))];
                        out_ptr0[static_cast<long>(x1 + (3L*x2) + (150528L*x0))] = tmp0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp single
        {
            {
                #pragma GCC ivdep
                for(long x0=static_cast<long>(0L); x0<static_cast<long>(64L); x0+=static_cast<long>(1L))
                {
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(long x1=static_cast<long>(0L); x1<static_cast<long>(3L); x1+=static_cast<long>(1L))
                    {
                        #pragma GCC ivdep
                        for(long x2=static_cast<long>(0L); x2<static_cast<long>(49L); x2+=static_cast<long>(1L))
                        {
                            auto tmp0 = in_ptr1[static_cast<long>(x2 + (49L*x1) + (147L*x0))];
                            out_ptr1[static_cast<long>(x1 + (3L*x2) + (147L*x0))] = tmp0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I configured 64 threads for parallel computation!
I added a line of code to print the thread ID and the total number of threads.——"printf("Current thread ID: %d, all thread nums: %d\n", tid, t_nums);"
Then, I compiled this code into a dynamic library using GCC. I added the OpenMP enablement flag, and later testing in the Python environment showed that the dynamic library behaves as expected.
g++ /home/admin/zy429782/alibaba/aios/basic_ops/testdata/pytorch_models/resnet18_cpu/data/t7/ct73jxe2z6yybfbkncpbmdx6egd236o66jam7hou27boj5eumdpl.cpp -fPIC -Wall -std=c++17 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unknown-pragmas -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/include/python3.8 -mavx512f -mavx512dq -mavx512vl -mavx512bw -mfma -D CPU_CAPABILITY_AVX512 -O3 -DNDEBUG -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -ffp-contract=off -march=native -fopenmp -D TORCH_INDUCTOR_CPP_WRAPPER -D C10_USING_CUSTOM_GENERATED_MACROS -c -o /home/admin/zy429782/alibaba/aios/basic_ops/testdata/pytorch_models/resnet18_cpu/data/t7/ct73jxe2z6yybfbkncpbmdx6egd236o66jam7hou27boj5eumdpl.o

g++ /home/admin/zy429782/alibaba/aios/basic_ops/testdata/pytorch_models/resnet18_cpu/data/t7/ct73jxe2z6yybfbkncpbmdx6egd236o66jam7hou27boj5eumdpl.o /home/admin/zy429782/alibaba/aios/basic_ops/testdata/pytorch_models/resnet18_cpu/data/7e/c7eavtek6ibammokniksmjwkgefuz6cjrgpw46g7vvm5ts6rb42t.o -shared -fPIC -Wall -std=c++17 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unknown-pragmas -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/include/python3.8 -L/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib -L/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib -L/home/admin/zy429782/miniforge3/envs/torch240_cuda121/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib -ltorch -ltorch_cpu -lgomp -lc10 -mavx512f -mavx512dq -mavx512vl -mavx512bw -mfma -D CPU_CAPABILITY_AVX512 -O3 -DNDEBUG -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -ffp-contract=off -march=native -fopenmp -D TORCH_INDUCTOR_CPP_WRAPPER -D C10_USING_CUSTOM_GENERATED_MACROS -o resnet18_cpu.so

Since I used PyTorch's aot_compile feature to generate the C++ code, I can load this dynamic library directly in the Python environment. Essentially, it's still calling the functions within the library, just like any regular dynamic library loading.
import torch
model = torch._export.aot_load('resnet18_cpu.so', 'cpu')
print(model(torch.ones(4, 3, 224, 224)))

The output looks like this, and everything works as expected:
Current thread ID: 24, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 48, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 6, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 49, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 40, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 46, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 58, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 1, all thread nums: 64

.................

Current thread ID: 17, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 57, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 11, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 25, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 43, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 44, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 62, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 34, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 20, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 8, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 42, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 14, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 36, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 56, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 22, all thread nums: 64
tensor([[-0.0391,  0.1145, -1.7968,  ..., -1.5152,  0.1724,  0.1825],
        [-0.0391,  0.1145, -1.7968,  ..., -1.5152,  0.1724,  0.1825],
        [-0.0391,  0.1145, -1.7968,  ..., -1.5152,  0.1724,  0.1825],
        [-0.0391,  0.1145, -1.7968,  ..., -1.5152,  0.1724,  0.1825]])
>>> 

However, when I write a custom operator in C++ TensorFlow and load this dynamic library for inference, the code looks something like this:
_aotiModelContainerRunner = std::make_shared<torch::inductor::AOTIModelContainerRunnerCpu>(modelFilePath);
vector<at::Tensor> realOutputs = _aotiModelContainerRunner->run(realInputs);

Strangely, all the printed thread IDs are 0, yet the total number of threads is indeed 64.
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64

...........................

Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64
Current thread ID: 0, all thread nums: 64

Moreover, the computation results are wildly incorrect, with NAN values appearing.
  "output tensors: (0th) Shape:[4,1000], Content:[-nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan -nan 

I believe there must be some setting affecting OpenMP's expected behavior. Even after adding 'export OMP_NUM_THREADS=64', it didn't help. I also created a symlink for /lib64/libgomp.so.0.1 pointing to the libgomp library in my conda environment, but that didn't work either. Something is definitely impacting OpenMP's expected behavior, but after searching for a long time, I still haven't found a solution. Does anyone have any ideas or thoughts on possible causes?
$ldd /home/admin/zy429782/.sandbox/bazel-sandbox.1866e40fc46b8e58d1839b91358c2661f1ec6978b8ad743585739725887aba2e/linux-sandbox/13/execroot/com_taobao_aios/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/aios/basic_ops/basic_ops/ops/model/pytorch_model_predict_op_test.runfiles/com_taobao_aios/aios/basic_ops/basic_ops/ops/model/pytorch_model_predict_op_test | grep gomp
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f97c1644000)

$ldd resnet18_cpu.so | grep omp
libgomp.so.1 => /lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f0aafce2000)
"I hope to find the cause of the bug or a way to work around it."

When I commented out the OpenMP-related #pragma directives, everything worked normally, and the computation results were correct.

BTW: “who“ asks which person. You want to know “what“ interfered. English is weirdly particular about that.

sorry, I would like to modify my statement, please forgive me for not being a native English speaker.

I know. Don’t ever feel bad for making a mistake, especially a very small one. Learning is cool! :-)

You are nice man!

As was previously suggested (though the comment seems to have now vanished), this could very well be the result of loading both libgomp.so (the GCC OpenMP runtime) and libomp.so (the LLVM OpenMP runtime). This could happen if another part of the code uses OpenMP and has been compiled with LLVM (clang/clang++). I explained why this doesn;t work in a recent(-ish) blog post https://cpufun.substack.com/p/is-mixing-openmp-runtimes-safe . To investigate, the LD_DEBUG envirable may be useful. See https://bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html

thank you, jim! Inspired by you, I've identified the issue: PyTorch relies on a specific commit ID of libgomp, not the one that comes with GCC.

The OpenMP multithreading issue arises because PyTorch relies on a specific commit ID of libgomp.so. For example, when downloading torch-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl from pytorch.org and renaming it to .zip, extracting it reveals libgomp-a34b3233.so.1 in the torch/lib directory. Some behaviors in PyTorch, especially in libtorch_cpu.so, depend on this modified OpenMP library.
However, there is another libgomp.so.1 library located in /lib64, which behaves differently. The forward logic of nn.Module compiled by Torch Inductor uses the system's gcc, relying on /lib64/libgomp.so.1. Thus, my executable prioritizes loading this system library.
To fix this, preload libgomp-a34b3233.so.1 before running the program, for example, by using LD_PRELOAD=libgomp-a34b3233.so.1.
-----------update----------------------
Using LD_PRELOAD resolved the unexpected behavior of OpenMP in unit tests, but the issue persists in the online service environment, suggesting the problem lies elsewhere. After thorough inspection, I confirmed there are no other OpenMP implementations on the system. I am uncertain if it might be due to TensorFlow's thread pool causing the issue.
